# How do I define the amount of decimal places in a Single-type variable in Inno Setup?

Tags: decimal, inno-setup, rounding, pascalscript

I need to calculate the total size of all components in my setup. Because of some custom code I cannot use Inno Setup's internal feature for that.

The problem was that the components share a lot of files. So I defined a string for every component which contains variables for the files they use. I then have these strings added into a single string and if a certain variable is found in this string, then the size of the file in bytes is added to the variable "size" of type `Single`.
In the end "size" shows how much space is needed for the installation.

Actually this works pretty well, but I then want to show the size in GB in the next page.
But the function `FloatToStr` adds a lot of numbers after the decimal point whereas I just want to have two.

Here's the script (the problem occurs in the very last lines):

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  size: Single;

  if (CurPageID = wpSelectDir) then { I have swapped the Components and SelectDir pages }
  begin

  size := 0; { this will contain the size in the end }
  xg := '';  { this is the string which contains the list of files needed by every single component }
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(ComponentArray) - 1 do
  if IsComponentSelected(ComponentArray[I].Component) then
  begin
    xg := xg + ComponentArray[I].GCF; 
  end;    
  { here the files are being added to the string, everything's working as intended.. }


  MsgBox(xg, mbInformation, MB_OK); { this is for testing if the string has been created correctly }
  if Pos('gcf1', xg) > 0 then size := size + 1512820736; { here the Pos-function searches for the given string and if it is found it adds the value to "size", ok... }
  if Pos('gcf2', xg) > 0 then size := size + 635711488;
  if Pos('gcf3', xg) > 0 then size := size + 286273536;
size := size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; { now all sizes have been added and the number is converted to be displayed GB, not bytes }
  { Format('%.2n', [size]); }
  { size := (round(size * 10) / 10); }
  { size := Format('%.2n', [size]); }
  { FloatToStr(size); }
  MsgBox(FloatToStr(size), mbInformation, MB_OK); { Here the size is shown but with several unneeded places after the decimal point (2.267589569092) }
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, I tried several things to get rid of the numbers. The problem is the `FloatToStr` function in the `MsgBox`, it automatically adds all the numbers. If I choose the type `Integer` for "size" it still shows that long number but I cannot use `Integer` and `IntToStr` in the `MsgBox` (what would solve the problem), because the numbers handled here are too big and I want to have two decimal places after the point.

I also tried to put the `Format` function into the `MsgBox` but I got a *"Type mismatch"* error as well.

`FloatToStrF` is not supported by Inno Setup.

Converting "size" using `FloatToStr` beforehand and truncating it didn't work as well, because the compiler checks what type "size" was declared as and insists on using `FloatToStr` in the `MsgBox` again.

I have no clue how to round this number up. Maybe some different approach would help?

I am looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Format`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_format.htm) function.

Take a look at this example:

```pascal
procedure TestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Extended;
begin
  Size := 0;
  Size := Size + 1512820736
  Size := Size + 635711488;
  Size := Size + 286273536;
  Size := Size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; { now all sizes have been added and the number is converted to be displayed GB, not bytes }
  MsgBox(Format('%.2f Gb.', [Size]), mbInformation, MB_OK); 
end;
```

I'm changing the data type from `Single` to `Extended`, take it as a personal choice.

Or use this function as a *smarter* choice to add the correct dimensional depending on the byte count:

```pascal
const
  KFactor = 1024;

function FormatBytes(const Bytes: Extended): string;
var
  Amount: Extended;
  Idx: Byte;
  Dms: array[1..5] of string;
  FmtStr: string;
begin
  Dms[1] := 'B'; Dms[2] := 'KB'; Dms[3] := 'MB'; Dms[4] := 'GB'; Dms[5] := 'TB';
  Amount := Bytes;
  Idx := 1;
  while Amount > (0.9 * KFactor) do
  begin
    Idx := Idx + 1;
    Amount := Amount / KFactor;
  end;
  if Abs(Amount - Trunc(Amount)) < 0.07 then
    FmtStr := '%.0f %s'
  else
    FmtStr := '%.2f %s';
  Result := Format(FmtStr, [Amount, Dms[Idx]]);
end;
```

Answer edited to adjust the number of decimal places in case of a near exact amount of KB/MB/GB/TB is to be shown.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I used the Format function incorrectly but now it works! But I am still struggling to understand how the second function works... Could you explain it a little bit, please?

Comment: @user1662035 Sorry I think the code speaks for itself. If you are trying to figure out how this work, you may want to debug it and run it step by step. Put a breakpint (F5) at the first line, and once it stops the installer execution, you can go on with step over (F8) while inspecting the variable values by hovering the mouse cursor over it's name in the script.

Comment: const KFactor = 1024; I didn't notice it was not included.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and I now understand why this solution is better. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Uh, another question... Can I get rid of trailing zeros using this function? For example, how can I convert 716,00 MB to 716 MB?

Comment: Sure you can, just change the format string to suit your needs!

Comment: Sorry, I looked at some detailes explanations of the Format function but I still do not know how to accomplish this...

Comment: @user For example, you can make the format string a variable also and adjust it to the number of decimals you want. I edited my question to improve this.